Copy mysql db field to another field
I have a database table with thousands of products. Each product have various fields. There is a field (field1) on each product that contain a link, I need that link to be copied to another product field called field2. I need this task to cover all the products. How can I achieve that ? Some of the field2 fields already have the need it link and some of the field1 fields can be empty, so the action should only copy the field1 only if it has data on it.
Here is a sample of my table with products
Here is a sample of what I need to achieve with every product mentioned field

I updated the request with images.

UPDATE cscart_products SET wk_buy_now_url = buy_now_url WHERE buy_now_url IS NOT NULL

Hello @Justinas, how to deleted all cscart_products tables that have empty field buy_now_url  ?
